# Bash script that lists files in a directory doesn't work

Tags: bash, shell, ffmpeg, mp4, mov

I made a bash script because I need to convert a lot of files in a directory from .MOV to .mp4 format.
I created this script for the purpose:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch .lista
ls -1 "$1" | grep -i .MOV > .lista
list= `pwd`/.lista
cd "$1"
while read -r line;
    do filename=${line%????}
    ffmpeg -i "$line" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "$filename.mp4"; done < $list
rm .lista
```

This script is supposed to convert me each .MOV file into the directory indicated by $1, but it doesn't work, it converts me only one file, then it terminates. I can't understand why. What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 2):

It's better to simply loop using globs:

```
for file in "$1"/*.MOV; do
    ffmpeg -i "$file" ... "${file%.*}.mp4" 
done
```

[Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 2):

Do them all fast and succinctly in parallel with **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
parallel --dry-run ffmpeg -i {} -vcodec copy -acodec copy {.}.mp4 ::: movies/*MOV
```

**Sample Output**

```
ffmpeg -i movies/a.MOV -vcodec copy -acodec copy movies/a.mp4
ffmpeg -i movies/b.MOV -vcodec copy -acodec copy movies/b.mp4
```

If that looks good, do it again but without `--dry-run`.

Note how easily **GNU Parallel** takes care of all the loops, all the quoting and changing the extension for you.

Comment: I'm gonna try this way very soon. Unfortunately my router is broken, due to a lighting bolt tempest happened yesterday, so I can't download GNU Parallel at the moment.

Comment: Cool - I'm sure you'll enjoy the ease of use and especially the performance especially in this world where CPUs are hardly getting much faster but are getting more and more cores, so parallel solutions are increasingly appropriate to make the most of them.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working for me. I cannot see any error. But I can suggest you a better approach. Don't use `ls` to get the filenames, it is not a good idea. Also, you can avoid changing dir.

```
#!/bin/bash

for line in $(find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.mov")
do
    ffmpeg -i "$line" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "${line%????}.mp4"
done
```

You don't need to start by touching the file. In any case, you don't need a file at all, you can use a `for` loop to iterate over the files returned by find directly. With `find`, I'm already selecting all the files in the specified folder that have the expected extension.

Here I add a one-liner that should avoid problems with spaces:

```
find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.mov" -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -I{} bash -c "F={}; ffmpeg -i \"\$F\" -vcodec copy -acodec copy \"\${F%.*}\".mp4"
```

Comment: It would be much better use the globs as in PesaThe's answer, because the words could break if the filenames contain spaces

Comment: That's why I use "read -r line"...spaces in the names gave me a lot of problems. Anyway thanks to both for the tips